# problem facing in lazy loading in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, lazy-loading, angular8

structure is

```
1--login component
  1.1--forget password component
  1.2--reset password component
```

For that I created the module named "login module"

Here is my coding:

app.routing

```
 {
path: '',
redirectTo: 'login',
pathMatch: 'full',

 },
 {
   path: 'login',
   component: LoginComponent,

   children: [
    {
      path: 'login',
      canActivate: [AuthServiceGuard],
      loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule'
    }
   ]
 }
```

login.routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {
  path:'',
  component : LoginComponent,
  data:{
    title:'login'
  },
   children:[{
      path:'forgotPassword',
      component:forgotPwdComponent,
      data:{
        title:'ForgotPassword'
      }
    },
   {
      path:'resetPassword',
      component:ResetPwdComponent,
      data:{
        title:'ResettPassword'
      }
    }]
```

And in login.html i used routerLink as,

```
<a class="achortag" routerLink="/forgotPassword">Forgot Password</a>
```

Now getting error like:

---

```
core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'forgotPassword'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'forgotPassword'
```

---

I called forgetpwdComponent and resetpwdcomponent in loginmodule and

I called loginmodule in appmodule
Is there any problem in my step which I did.

can anybody guide me??

Answer (score 1):

currently your forgot password route is `/login/login/forgotPassword`

you can change your routing something like this

app.routing

```
[
   {
       path: '',
       redirectTo: 'login',
       pathMatch: 'full',
   },
   {
       path: '',
       canActivate: [AuthServiceGuard],
       loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule'
   }
]
```

in this case your route is `/login/forgotPassword`

if you want to have the route `/forgotPassword` instead of `/login/forgotPassword`

you can change your code something like below

app.routing

```
[
  {
     path: '',
     canActivate: [AuthServiceGuard],
     loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule'
   }
]
```

login.routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
     path:'login',
     component : LoginComponent,
     data:{
     title:'login'
  },
  {
     path:'forgotPassword',
     component:forgotPwdComponent,
     data:{
        title:'ForgotPassword'
     }
   },
   {
      path:'resetPassword',
      component:ResetPwdComponent,
      data:{
         title:'ResettPassword'
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: that is not a routing, I am giving the modulename,login is my folder

Comment: @AngelReji Sorry I don't understand what you say, please can you clarify?

Comment: and I have updated the answer, you should not be import LoginComponent into `AppModule` if it is a part of `LoginModule`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
[routerLink]="['login/forgotPassword']
```